# htaccess redirect for http but exclude https

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am changing the domain of a website, however due to hosting restrictions the ssl connection has to use the old domain (for the time being at least). I am therefore trying to use .htaccess to redirect from one domain to another for http connections but not for those using https.

I have the following which isn't working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$ 

RewriteRule (.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be gratefully received. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should as your **very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Correct variable name `%{HTTP_HOST}`